# Instantiating a class from different .dll using reflection based on the class name?

Tags: c#, reflection

Is there any way to instantiate a class based it name from different project/.dll without using `dll = Assembly.LoadFile(@"c:\Test.dll");` and do `dll.CreateInstance(className);`

I want to be able to load different class which implementing a common Interface in my application without need recompiling (something like a plugin). The dll is in the application path.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You'll need to know which assembly to load it from *somehow*... then you can use `Type.GetType(name)` where the name you pass is qualified with the assembly name as well.

Comment: so it is impossible to automatically load a dll by only giving the class name? Either I provide the full path of the dll or installing the dll in GAC are the only way?

Comment: @nandaka: Even putting it in the GAC you'd have to give the assembly name. Bare in mind that there could be any number of assemblies, and multiple assemblies could each have a class of the same name.

Comment: I see, this is what I do for now:
`IPlugin plugin = Activator.CreateInstance(_fullname, className).Unwrap() as IPlugin;`

I can get the namespace by splitting the fullname `_fullname.Split(',')[0]+ ".PluginHelloWorld"`

Answer (score 0):

I don't think there is any way to find a Dll based on only a class name or an interface a class implements, except for just finding and opening each Dll in the directory. You could use the `ReflectionOnlyLoad*` methods to reduce some overhead while finding the correct Dll.

Comment: what is the difference with Assembly.LoadFile() ? When I tried to use Assembly.ReflectionOnlyLoadFrom(), it said that I should create an event to load the dll, basically the same thing with Assembly.LoadFile() then?

Comment: Using ReflectionOnlyLoad, you prevent dependencies from being loaded - when opening all those Dll's from the current directory you don't know what you'd end up loading otherwise. When you find the assembly matching the right type, you can load that one using `LoadFile()`.